# How to create classes from existing tables using Flask-SQLaclhemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I know I need to use the MetaData object, in SQLAlchemy, but I am not sure how to use it with a class,

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
meta =db.Metadata()
class orders(db.model):
  pass
```

How do I pass the meta object to the class so that it will auto generate table schema?

Answer (score 7):

Well you can use SQLAlchemy's autoload feature but I still haven't figured out how to use that from flask-sqlalchemy. Here's a tutorial if you want to read about it anyway: [SQLAlchemy Connecting to pre-existing databases](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/09/10/sqlalchemy-connecting-to-pre-existing-databases/).
The best solution I found for the time being is to use [sqlautocode](http://turbogears.org/2.1/docs/main/Utilities/sqlautocode.html) to generate the SQLAlchemy models from the existing tables in your database. I know it would be preferable if SQLAlchemy would handle that automatically but I can't find a way to do it from Flask.

Here's how to use it:

```
sqlautocode mysql://<dbuser>:<pass>@localhost:3306/<dbname> -o alchemy_models.py
```

This will generate the Models and place them in the `alchemy_models.py` file. I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the tip about sqlautocode. As an update, sqlautocode is now superceded by [sqlacodegen](https://bitbucket.org/agronholm/sqlacodegen) which supports SQLAlchemy 0.6 - 1.0 and is Python3 compatible.

Comment: Here is a working link for [sqlacodegen](https://pypi.org/project/sqlacodegen/).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [sqlacodegen](https://pypi.org/project/sqlacodegen/) to generate the classes needed for sqlalchemy.

```
pip install sqlacodegen

sqlacodegen postgresql+psycopg2://username:password@host/database --outfile models.py
```

I ran into an issue with the Base class and the query attribute. The error I received was:

```
AttributeError: type object 'PaymentType' has no attribute 'query'
```

I was able to make the sqlacodegen classes work by using a scoped_session.

```
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,autoflush=False,bind=engine))
Base.query = session.query_property()
print(PaymentType.query.all())
```

Answer (score 0):

The `db.Model.metadata.reflect(...)` function is also super useful here; you don't have to define the model at all (it's just inferred from the existing database schema).

See [stay_hungry's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55088156/6794367) for a specific implementation