# how to reflect an existing table by using flask_sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I've  notice a method:

```
db.reflect(bind='__all__',app=app)
```

but i wonder how to use it.
I'd appreciate it if you can help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'database connect url'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.Model.metadata.reflect(bind=db.engine,schema='DATABASE_NAME')

class User(db.Model):
    '''deal with an existing table'''
    __table__ = db.Model.metadata.tables['DATABASE_NAME.TABLE_NAME']

u = User.query.all()
print(u)
db.commit()
```

Comment: this code will not work if you are having multiple schemas..